# Problem adding to favorites with React Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, filter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to code the "add to favorite" feature to a blog using firebase. To do so, I had an idea which consists in filtering an array containing all the articles and keep only the user's favorite ones. The problem is that  I need a field value (isFavorite), which is a boolean, to check if it is one of the user's favorite articles or not but this forces me use .then() to grab this boolean. Unfortunately I think this .then() makes my .filter() not filtering anything.

If you have an idea of how to grab this field value with an expression which would work in a .filter() condition, please let me know

```
    export default function FavoriteCardlist() {
  const [favoriteArticles, setFavoriteArticles] = useState([]);
  const [uid, setUid] = useRecoilState(userIDCheck);

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("articles").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      setFavoriteArticles(
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          article: doc.data(),
        }))
      );
    });
  }, []);

  const favoriteArticlesList = favoriteArticles
    .filter((article) =>
      db
        .collection("users")
        .doc(uid)
        .collection("favoriteArticles")
        .doc(article.id)
        .get()
        .then((doc) => doc.data()?.isFavorite)
    )
    .map((article) => (
      <div key={article.id}>
        <h2>{article.article.title}</h2>
      </div>
    ));

  return <div className="cardlist">{favoriteArticlesList}</div>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible you're

```
.then((doc) => doc.data()?.isFavorite)
```

isn't returning a value as the promise is just resolving hence why your filter isn't working.

In your "favoriteArticles" collection does each document also have a "isFavorite" field?

If an article is already stored against a user as a favorite and a favorite again this sounds redundant. It also looks like you're making a request for all the articles and then filtering through them which will cost more and take longer.

If this is for a single page and you don't need all the articles then instead you could do the initial request for the users favorite article ID's and then make a request to the articles collection using the constructed array of ID's. e.g:

```
firestore()
        .collection("users")
        .doc(uid)
        .collection("favoriteArticles")
        .get()
.then(querySnapshot => {
 querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
// update state array with article id
    });
  });


firestore()
  .collection('articles')
  .where('id', 'in',[arrayOfFavoriteID's])
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
  // updateState for div to map through and render
  });
```

Comment: Thank you very much @mancony for the suggestion ! I put your code in a useEffect and managed to have [arrayOfFavoriteID's] work well even though I had to put a new field to each article "id": 0LefJksmq.. The poblem is when I map, it gives me only one of my 3 favorite articles whereas I have the right array of favourite article's ID. Also with this method, will I be limited to have only 10 favorite articles ?

Comment: No problem. Did you manually add an id field to each article? You should just be able to get the auto-generated id using something like ```article.id``` inside the snapshot. Only getting 1 of the 3 sounds like the structure of the map isn't quite right. Would need to see the code to confirm but it sounds like you're not making a request for each document. You may need to wrap a Promise.all around the map of the articles as each of them will be a separate request. As each request is a promise, Promise.all should wait for each of them to resolve before updating state/component.

Comment: It is now working fine @mancony , in fact it was due to a typo in the id which i added manually in firebase for testing ^^. However I am limited to having 10 favorites maximum due to the "in" restriction. I am really thankful for your help and I'll try to find a workaround to have more than 10 favorites ! Again, thanks a lot, appreciate your help :)